# Linking to OWA Calendar - Passing a Time Zone

Tags: html, hyperlink, outlook-web-app, outlook-calendar

I am trying to prefill a create event link to Microsoft OWA.
This works:

```
https://outlook.live.com/owa/
    ?path=/calendar/action/compose
    &subject=TestEvent
    &location=testlocation
    &startdt=2018-02-29T19:00:00
    &enddt=2018-02-29T20:00:00
    &body=Testtext+my+test+text
```

[Test it here](https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/calendar/action/compose&subject=TestEvent&location=testlocation&startdt=2018-02-29T19:00:00&enddt=2018-02-29T20:00:00&body=Testtext%20my%20test%20text)

But I did not find a way to set a timezone, since for some reason [that is not documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846807.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#single).
Is there a way to set the timezone of `startdt` and `enddt`?

I already tried appending a Z to the date, as this works in Yahoo and Google Calendar links (it tells the application that the timezone is UTC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also been unable to discover how to set a timezone for the OWA calendar event link.  However, I have discovered that you can specify a UTC offset value within the link.  There are two drawbacks to this method though.  The first drawback is that you have to account for daylight savings time on your end, because the UTC offset changes.  The second is that the end user needs to have their timezone set correctly for them to see the correct time.

How you specify the UTC offset within the link is by adding the offset to the end of the `startdt` and `enddt` parameters in the format of + or - hh:mm.  For example, let's say the event was set for March 27, 3pm, in the Eastern standard time zone.  In the US, daylight savings is active on March 27, so the UTC offset would be -4 for the eastern US.  The `startdt` parameter should then be `2018-03-27T15:00:00-04:00`.  Same goes for the `enddt` parameter.

Comment: Hey, apparently it is in utc by default, and it calculates the time zone for owa users automatically. Thanks for your answer!